# Open link send parameter POST

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How does open link website send variable for POST? Below when I open a link I use this code

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.google.com");
```

But I would like to send 3 parameters for POST.

Comment: Post indicates that the request contains a body.  You are sending only a URL with no body.

Comment: Do you mean with in-lined query tuples? As `https://somesite.com?Option1=Value1&Option2=Value2`? If you need to make an actual POST request, use HttpClient.

Comment: I need open browser and set the link and send togheter 3 parameter